# Modx Login Color Style

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, modx-revolution

i use modx revolution 2.4 since some weeks and its login extra(plugin) to manage page permissions. 
Everything works fine, but there is a yellow background color in the html input tags of the login form that can't be styled by my css stylesheet.
The color is also present on the regular modx login, so maby the style comes from an priorized stylesheet of modx.

i tried the following:

- search the web
- css style: `input{ background: #fff !important;}`
- looking for priorized stylesheets in
  manager/templates/default/css/login.css and
  manager/templates/default/css/index.css
- find stylesheets with the browser->view source code
- add style directly to html input tag

but with no luck.

the html code of the login form looks as follows:

```
<div class="loginForm">
    <div class="loginMessage">[[+errors]]</div>
    <div class="loginLogin">
        <form class="loginLoginForm" action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post">
            <fieldset class="loginLoginFieldset">
                <legend class="loginLegend">[[+actionMsg]]</legend>
                <label class="loginUsernameLabel">[[%login.username]]
                    <input class="loginUsername" type="text" name="username" />
                </label>

                <label class="loginPasswordLabel">[[%login.password]]
                    <input class="loginPassword" type="password" name="password" />
                </label>
                <input class="returnUrl" type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="[[+request_uri]]"/>

                [[+login.recaptcha_html]]

                <input class="loginLoginValue" type="hidden" name="service" value="login"/>
                <span class="loginLoginButton"><input type="submit" name="Login" value="[[+actionMsg]]" /></span>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css code part of my stylesheet looks like:

```
input{
    background: #fff !important;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 110%;
}
```

Comment: any chance we can see that website in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This yellow because autocomplite. How to disable - http://makandracards.com/makandra/24933-chrome-34+-firefox-38+-ie11+-ignore-autocomplete-off